# Need to create valid JSON string in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am writing an Azure Logic App to read my Azure Monitor logs, and trigger the Teams channel webhook if there are any Sev3 messages.

What I'd really like to do is have each message on a separate line (facts), with the timestamp as the key, and the message as the value.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "facts": [
        {
          "11:00": "message1"
        },
        {
          "11:01": "message2"
        }
      ],
      "title": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
}
```

To this end, I was trying to programmatically build the JSON for each log message coming back from the query, in proper JSON format.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "facts": [
        "@substring(variables('MessageString'), 0, sub(length(variables('MessageString')), 1))"
      ],
      "title": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
}
```

The problem is, when the Logic App evaluates my computed JSON data, it's putting quotes around the entire variable, and then escaping all the quotes within the data. This gives me a JSON error at runtime.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "facts": [
        "{\"2023-08-29T22:00:22.888Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 18:00:22.547 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Poller service docker container innovation-fsb-kinatrax-poller-service is not running\"},{\"2023-08-29T22:00:22.322Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 18:00:22.042 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Processes not running = KinaTrax_Acquisition, node:kinatrax-store-server-service,KinatraxCameraService\"},{\"2023-08-29T21:59:49.161Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 17:59:48.429 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Poller service docker container innovation-fsb-kinatrax-poller-service is not running\"},{\"2023-08-29T21:59:48.193Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 17:59:47.756 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Processes not running = KinaTrax_Acquisition, node:kinatrax-store-server-service,KinatraxCameraService\"}"
      ],
      "title": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
}
```

I've tried a number of different things, but they have mostly causes compile syntax errors in the logic.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting rid of the outer quotes and escaped quotes inside the JSON?

Comment: Is that an adaptive card you're posting?

Comment: Whats your input, provide us with your hardcoded input

Comment: 1. According to the doc, you can't use adaptive cards for Teams webhooks.
2. The hardcoded input is exactly what you see in the output above, without the escaping of the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results:

**`Input which i gave to logic app:`**

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "facts": [
        [
  "{\"2023-08-29T22:00:22.888Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 18:00:22.547 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Poller service docker container innovation-fsb-kinatrax-poller-service is not running\"},{\"2023-08-29T22:00:22.322Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 18:00:22.042 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Processes not running = KinaTrax_Acquisition\"},{\"2023-08-29T21:59:49.161Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 17:59:48.429 - kinarver-processes.ps1: Poller service docker contr inrithnovation-fsb-kinatrax-poller-service is not running\"},{\"2023-08-29T21:59:48.193Z\": \"ERROR: KHM: 2023-08-29 17:59:47.756 - kinatrax-monitor-server-processes.ps1: Processes not running = KinaTrax_Acquisition\"}"
]
      ],
      "title": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
}
```

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then:
[image]

```
json(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(items('For_each_3'),'\\\',''),'\',''),'[',''),']',''),'"{','{'),'}"',''))
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Codeview to replicate the same with my input:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@split(variables('var'),',')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "facts": "@variables('var2')",
                            "title": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
                        }
                    ],
                    "summary": "BatFitting 2.0 Dev - Alerts"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_string_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "var",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each_2')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@items('For_each')['facts']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['sections']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_3": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "value": "@json(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(items('For_each_3'),'\\\\\\',''),'\\',''),'[',''),']',''),'\"{','{'),'}\"',''))"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@outputs('Compose')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "sections": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "facts": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": "array"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "title": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "facts",
                                        "title"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            },
                            "summary": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

**`Note:`**

In input inside facts array, you only need to have commas when you are separating jsons  not inside the json.

Comment: Wow, thanks for going to all the trouble to come up with and document the solution!